# How is mirror cloning in git so fast and small?

Tags: git

I was doing some potentially dangerous history rewriting, so I decided to make a clone with `--mirror` option. I was surprised by the blazing fast cloning operation. And, somehow the resulting repo is less than 1MB while the original repo was more than 300MB (after `git gc --aggressive`). How is this possible? Does `git clone --mirror` use some sort of magic? or am I losing data when I clone with `--mirror`

I used `du -s` to see how much disk space it occupies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is not in the `--mirror` option but in the `--local` one, which is the default for clones in the same filesystem:

> `--local` [...] The files under .git/objects/ directory are hardlinked
>              to save space when possible.

So both repositories actually share disk space.

You can clone with the `--no-hardlinks` and check the resulting size.

Comment: @Memming: No, hardlinks are not _copy-on-write_. But that should not affect git operation. Git is smart enough so that there is no operation in the repository (other than file corruption) that will affect the cloned one. Note that this is true for repositories cloned with `--local`, but not with `--shared`.